# Can you add a component to state with Hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a modal that I'm using to allow editing of individual pieces of a page with a lot of discrete sections. This is a lot more user-friendly than passing them to a form - the form would be enormous.

The sections across the page vary though. Some are simple text and a simple textarea or input will suffice. Some data though can only be edited with a select (or conceivably multiple selects).

For the textareas, I am using the following:

```
/* inplace-edit dialog */
const [dialog, setDialog] = useState({
    open: false, // whether dialog should show
    fieldName: null, // reference to field for db update on submit
    title: '', // dialog title
    content: '', // data to show in dialog content
})

const setDialogState = update => () => {
  setDialog({ ...dialog, ...update })
}
```

As a functional component is essentially a function, **is it viable to add that component to the state** and then use that component to render the specific form structure when the dialog needs to show?

Comment: It is possible to add a component to state. But it is not advised to do so. Always add state holding the necessary data to render the component.

Comment: Adding a component in state is buggy in the scenario where you need to update the component some how and then you might have to clone it for setDialog to work properly.  Cloning it can become challenging when your component is compound component consisting of many other components and changes are at different level.
Hence we usually keep data in state not component objects. This is my understanding aboot it. Feel free to correct me If i am wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done some more investigation and it seems viable to add a stateless component to state using hooks.

I've modified the state handling code to:

```
  const [dialog, setDialog] = useState({
    open: false,
    title: '',
    formComponent: () => null,
  })

  const setDialogState = update => () => {
    setDialog({ ...dialog, ...update })
  }
```

In the above `formComponent` is just a default function that returns null.

In a page section that I want to edit, there is a boolean `showEditIcons` that shows the edit icon if the viewer has appropriate permissions. On clicking the icon, it sets the state. And most importantly, it sets `formComponent` as a reference to the stateless function:

```
        {showEditIcons && (
          <IconButton
            onClick={setDialogState({
              open: true,
              title: 'Project Summary',
              formComponent: TextForm,
            })}
          >
            <EditIcon />
          </IconButton>
        )}
```

where TextForm is just a function:

```
const TextForm = ({ handleSubmit }) => (
  <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
    <Field name="content">{({ field }) => <TextArea field={field} />}</Field>
  </form>
)
```

I don't see any issue with assigning a function as an object property. Happens all the time.

The real interesting part of course is how I use TextForm. I pass the `dialog` values as props to a `Dialog` component:

`<Dialog {...dialog} />`

And in the part of the Dialog where I need the form, I use the `TextForm` to render the form with `createElement`

```
  <DialogHeader>{title}</DialogHeader>
    <DialogContent>
      {React.createElement(formComponent)}
    </DialogContent>
  <DialogFooter ... />
```